# Why does an OpenGL texture render fine when running with the debugger in Eclipse, but render white when running the app on its own?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I have a sprite class and another class that extends the sprite class using an OpenGLSurvace view to render.  It looks something like this

```
public class Invader extends Sprite {

    static int mTextureId = -1;

    Invader(Context context, float x, float y, float angle)
    {
        super(context, x, y, angle);
        super.setSize(width, height);
//      super.setPos(x, y);
//      super.setAngle(angle);

        // Check to see if the texture is loaded already.  If it is a valid texture
        // id, don't bother loading it again
        if (mTextureId < 0)
        {
            super.loadBitmap(context.getResources(), R.drawable.piano_key_white);
        }
        else
        {
            super.setTexture(mTextureId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected int getTexture()
    {
        return mTextureId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setTexture(int textureId)
    {
        mTextureId = textureId; 
    }

}
```

As you can see, it uses a static pointer to a texture that is loaded with the loadBitmap function that calls the decodeResource function to create an OpenGL texture.  When I run the app from the debugger through Eclipse with the SDK plugin, everything looks great.  When I run the app normally on the phone, everything renders fine except this class which renders the Invader as a white square (which is the object's color).

From what I've found, the texture is probably not properly loading, thus a plain white square is drawn.  I can't figure out why this works in Debug and not during normal execution.  Any ideas?  What is different when a program isn't being run with remote debugging?

Comment: Woah I answered before I even read the code. Umm, I have no idea what you're doing and you posted absolutely 0 OpenGL code so there is nothing for us to troubleshoot. Try my answer and if that doesn't work - then you are SOL and need to post some actual OpenGL code to get any further help.

Comment: Looking back at the code that I posted, I realize it doesn't have any OpenGL code.  I think I figured out what the error was, though.  I had a static reference to my Renderer object that was being reset when I started debug and freed then.  However, when I ran the program off of my phone without debug, the previous static reference already existed referencing a gl Texture ID, but the gl resource had been freed, thus creating a white box.

Comment: Please read my comment on your answer; I apologize if I sound rude but what you said makes no sense at all. Also, please PLEASE don't call anything a reference, it is confusing and non-existent in java.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Place the texture in the "res/drawable" folder
2. Disable scaling of the texture during loading, code for you:

Texture array allocation (duh ;))

```
// Texture and geometry data
private int [] m_textureID = new int[1];
```

and loading:

```
        // Load the texture from resource
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(m_resources, R.drawable.tex, options);

    gl.glGenTextures(1, m_textureID, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textureID[0]);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    // Free resources
    bitmap.recycle();

    // Do some error checking
    if(m_textureID[0] == 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture!");
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out; and I think this is a good lesson to learn.  My class looked liked something like this

```
public class Sprite {
    private static int mTextureID = -1;
    private static boolean mShouldLoadTexture = true;
...
    onReder(GL10 gl) {
         if (mShouldLoadTexture) {
               mTextureID = loadTexture(gl, someBitmap);
               mShouldLoadTexture = false;
         }
    }
}
```

Another static class contained a list of sprites

```
public static class SpriteList {
    private static Vector<Sprite> mSprites;
    ...
}
```

The difference between when I ran it as debug opposed to just running it from the launcher on the phone is that the package is all the **static** classes are reset, whereas the launcher on the phone does not reset the **static** classes, necessarily.

So, when I would first run it as *debug*, the class would see that it needed to load the texture, then allocate a texture pointer in the GL10 object, and assign that to the **static** mTextureID.  At this point mTextureID contains a valid GL texture pointer.

Now, I would then quit debug, disconnect from eclipse, and run the launcher on my phone.  Because the container of the Sprite class had not been reset, mTextureID still had some value that pointed to a non-existent GL texture id.  Additionally, mShouldLoadTexture would remain 'false', meaning that the class wouldn't try to reload the texture from the bitmap.  So, onRender() would try to use a pointer to an invalid texture id and render a white box instead.

I simplified the scenario to make it more understandable.  I know the static container doesn't make a whole lot of sense in this example, but thought it to be illustrative of what I found out was going on.  When I made the containing class to not be **static** anymore, everything worked like it should.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are not making any sense. First of all, the launcher has nothing to do with the execution or memory of your application other than sending an intent to start it. The memory and the execution is handled within the VM. Second, there should be no difference between running in debug mode vs running in release mode, at least not when it comes to values stored under static fields. Something is definitely wrong in your app and it isn't the static fields. It's possible that your application isn't quitting entirely when you think it does, and when you RESUME it the GL context is lost.

Comment: You are right and wrong.  Unfortunately I tried to use my understanding of C to explain java.  There should be no difference, but there is.  You are right that it is the program not fully shutting down opposed to pausing and resuming.  The difference between running in 'Debug' mode opposed to running from the launcher is that when running in 'Debug' mode, the program is fully halted before an intent to run the activity is sent, losing any static context that might have existed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the texture sizes are powers of 2. Various devices won't load textures correctly unless they conform to those sizing constaints.

IE

1x2
2x2
512x256
128x128
etc

Comment: The textures are all power of 2.  Is it possible that the image is changed to a non-power of 2 on compile if it is in the res/drawable-Xdpi/?  I tried putting the texture in the res/raw folder and it did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem. For me, my textures would load the first time I launched the app in debug mode, but if I exited the phone from the app and opened it back up again, all my textures went away. I couldn't get textures to load unless I launched the app again from within my IDE.

For me, I took the suggestion of removing static fields and that fixed it completely (I had a static field holding the angle of rotation of a square which would cycle through a set of different textures and a static field holding the number of the current texture in my list of textures).

I still don't understand exactly why having static fields causes this.

And for the record YES my textures were of dimensions of powers of 2 and I had them placed in the drawable-nodpi folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, problem was, that running when connected to adb invented some delays. This delays caused my app to work only under very specific conditions and not working at all without these delays. 
I hope this can help someone.